# vb6 use same button on 2 textbox

Tags: vb6, project, calculator

Hi our instructor asked us to create a calculator that only uses button
for the value input in, It should have enter value1 on 1st textbox and then the other value on the next textbox in vb6

is there a way to use the same button to enter a value on the next textbox?

lets say after you press button 3 it will show on textbox1

```
Text1.Text = "3"
```

my problem is it wont go to the next textbox after it show the number 3
I've already tried

```
    If Text2.Setfoucs = True Then
    Text2.Text = "3"
    Else
    Text1.Text = "3"
    End If
```

Its giving me error.

I just wanted to use the same button on the second textbox
after it was used on the 1st textbox

I thought of using another bunch of buttons and set visible = true after the
1st button was pressed so that the nextone will be

```
Text2.Text = "3"
```

Im just a beginner on VB6 any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

here is what the project looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmaxz.png

Comment: You asked for suggestions...name each control with a meaningful name.  It will help you code and debug, and would certainly help anyone else (like us) read your code and know which control was which.  Secondly, "Its giving me error." is not helpful.  A description of the error, and what line, would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244175%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is a function, not a variable, and it doesn't return a value, so you can't use it in an if clause.

Here is my suggestion to accomplish what you're trying to do:

Add a GotFocus event to each of your textboxes, that sets a variable. Like so:

```
Private selectedTxtBox As Integer

Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
    selectedTxtBox = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Text2_GotFocus()
    selectedTxtBox = 2
End Sub
```

Then on your button, you can do:

```
If selectedTxtBox = 1 Then
    Text1.Text = "3"
ElseIf selectedTxtBox = 2 Then
    Text2.Text = "3"
End If
```